# Tumblr default theme Optica grid cell amount and adding sidebar for tag cloud...?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, sidebar, tumblr-themes

Using Tumblr default theme optica (header on top). Using grid -post layout. Albeit it makes very many post cells (5 on my monitor) I'd like 2-3 cells in a grid - leaving space for side for those tumblr widgets (recently liked & similar posts) +plus space on side for a sidebar to have tag cloud.

I've tried css and jquery sidebars but not getting to work. Multitude of grid sells cover the sidebar and/or the sidebar appears between nav-menu and top posts.

The tag cloud I have generated by JS that does work. But positioning a sidebar is no luck :( Also it seems that it's unpossible to change Optica to grid a little less of those cells (2-3 horizontally) :(

Comment: ok flexbox I have managed to get to 3 columns. Now css-grid?

Answer (score 0):

I think TUmblr just reduced grid from max 5 to max 4...